# Остановка setInterval

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть функция

```
function rost() {
 setInterval(function() {
 $('#planka').animate({height: '+=50'}, 300 )

  }, 1);
}

$( document ).on( "vmousedown", "#igr", function() {
rost();
});
```

как ее правильно остановить?

```
function stop() {
    //тут остановить
    }

$( document ).on( "vmouseup", "#igr", function() {
stop();});
```

Comment: setInterval(function() { ... }, **1**); - на фига?

Comment: Логично,убрал,спасибо

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ваш вариант будет выглядеть примерно так:

```
var intervalTimer;

function rost() {
    intervalTimer = setInterval(function() {
        $('#planka').animate({height: '+=50'}, 300 )
    }, 1);
}

$(document).on( "vmousedown", "#igr", function() {
    rost();
});

function stop() {
    $('#planka').stop(true,true);
    clearInterval(intervalTimer);
    intervalTimer = 0;
}

$(document).on( "vmouseup", "#igr", function() {
    stop();
});
```

Comment: Странно,остановка не происходит

Comment: Попробуйте перед очисткой интервала выполнить `$('#planka').stop( true, true )`. Ответ дополнил.

Comment: Спасибо! Заработало